# Trigger Insert in database

Tags: sql, oracle, triggers, insert

```
CREATE OR REPLACE TRIGGER no8 BEFORE INSERT ON pegawai FOR EACH ROW 
   BEGIN 
     IF :NEW."gaji" BETWEEN '1000000' AND '3000000' THEN 
         insert into pegawai
              ("no_ktp", "nama", "jenis_kel", "alamat", 
              "tgl_lahir", "gaji", "no_dep")  
         values (:new."no_ktp", :new."nama", :new."jenis_kel", :new."alamat",
                  :new."tgl_lahir", :new."gaji", :new."no_dep"); 
     END IF; 
   END;
```

I tried to insert this query ,

INSERT INTO pegawai VALUES
       ('20104490002','NELA','2','SIDOARJO','14-AUG-1975', '900000', '5')

but it give me this error:

```
ORA-04098: trigger 'SYSTEM.VALIDASI' is invalid and failed
re-validation
```

Help me please..

Comment: First, don't create objects in the `SYSTEM` schema.  Second, what is the error you get when you create the trigger?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't use an insert statement on a trigger for a table that is object of the trigger. Mainly not a BEFORE. It could get an infinite loop.

If you are trying to alter the values you are inserting on the table you should just change the values of the fields on `:new.FIELD_NAME`

As an example:

```
IF :NEW."gaji" BETWEEN '1000000' AND '3000000' THEN
    --say that you need to change the value of :new."nama" just do:
    :new."nama":= 'new Value';
end if;
```

Comment: +1, but to be more accurate, it can't go into an infinite loop because the trigger won't work anyway - they'll get the "table is mutating" error.

Comment: @JeffreyKemp Yeah, I know that, thats because I use "it could" :)

Comment: In English, "it could" means it has the potential to do it - but in this case, there is no possibility of an infinite loop.